# gcc library to use more recent libraries

Tags: c++, proxy, shared-libraries

I have a small question, my guess is that it's not possible, but never know!

I'm developing plugins for Maya, and it's still compiled with gcc-4.1.2. But I'd like to code with the new C++0x. Is it possible to compile and create my shared object (let call it X.so) but then, through shared object (call X_proxy.so) that would map my function in X.so, but to used by a program with an older architecture.

The structure would be : Maya -> X_proxy.so -> X.so!

X_proxy would just be there to forward the call to X.so. This way, it would be easy to develop with new tools and make them compatible with old ones (or recent ones using old tools).

EDIT: Another solution that I see might be to compile *.cpp files in *.cpp.o files with the latest version of g++, but then using an older version of g++ to link them. Would that be possible ?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the names map OK you should be fine without a proxy. You need to make sure the Maya header files you are going to use work with the more modern compiler but hopefully that won't be a problem and just try it. Shared objects don't have to be compiled with the same compiler or written in the same language as the program that loads them and calls the functions.

Comment: but we have horrible problems when it's not the same compiler version! and between 4.1.2 and 4.6... there's a lot of difference and it just doesn't work!

Comment: what sort of problems? Linking or at runtime?

Comment: only runtime! Even on Autodesk website, they explain how to install gcc-4.1.2 to be able to develop plugins! But it would be nice to be able to code with the new features and have the old architecture using it. Technically, it's the same machine code, so, there might be so possibilities here...

Comment: I wonder if the runtime problems are because the newer library is asking the linker to link to different versions of some other library. It might be possible to identify the library versions referenced by the main program and make sure the header files for the plugin use a compatible API with these libraries. ldd is a starting point to find the libraries used by the runtime application

Comment: in our case, there's libc++ that is quite important!